# Linewrapping in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

I am using the following code:

```
        for (Paragraph p : paragraphs){
            JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane("text/html", p.text);
            jep.setSize(new Dimension(parent.width-10, Integer.MAX_VALUE));  
            jep.setEditable(false);
            jep.addHyperlinkListener(hll);
            String bodyRule = "body { font-family: " + mainFont.getFamily() + "; "
                + "font-size: " + mainFont.getSize() + "pt; }";
            ((HTMLDocument) jep.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule(bodyRule);
```

to create a list of `JEditorPane`s that contain paragraphs of text. The code above is called at the beginning of the program, when the paragraphs are read in from a text file. Later, they are added to a JPanel as follows:

```
        for (JEditorPane p : next.contents.keySet() ){
        ...
        this.add(p);
    }
```

The `...` contains logic for animating them onto the screen, which I have omitted becauseI don't think it's relevant.

My problem is that, when the text of a paragraph is too long to fit the page, I want to display it in multiple lines. As of now, it displays the entire paragraph on one line. I think this problem has something to do with the fact that I'm creating the JEditorPane's separately from when I display them. Interestingly, it seems to be calculating the height of each pane correctly (in the image below, the line displayed should be broken into four, 
and the pane is the correct height for four lines), but still it displays all the text only on one line.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

p.s. a JEditorPane is necessary because I need to implement html formatting with HyperlinkListeners. If there's a simpler component I can do so in and perhaps sidestep this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Try taking a look at the `Scrollable` interface, it may allow you to control the horizontal span of the `JEditorPane`

Comment: why don't you try setting height and width pf `JEditorPane` ?

Comment: Can you edit this post to include the code where you lay out the `JEditorPane`? This sort of problem can be caused by using a `LayoutManager` that doesn't respect the sizes of it's contained components.